# Show that the inclusion relation of Hardy spaces is proper

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

The definition of Hardy spaces for the unit disk is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Hardy_spaces_for_the_unit_disk).

It is clear that for $0<p<q\le\infty$, $H^q\subseteq H^p$, by Hölder's inequality. I'm asked to show that the inclusion relation is proper. Specifically,
(1) Show that $H^q\subsetneq H^p$, for $0<p<q\le\infty$.
(2) Show that $H^\infty\subsetneq\bigcap_{0<p<\infty}H^p$.

I failed to construct such holomorphic functions. Can anyone help me?

By the way, is it true that $\bigcup_{0<p<\infty}H^p\subsetneq N$, where $N$ is [Nevanlinna space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_type_(mathematics))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: (1) Look at functions of the form $f_a(z)=1/(1-z)^a$ for $a>0.$ Note that on the boundary we have

$$|f_a(e^{it})|^p = |1-e^{it}|^{-ap}$$

and that near $t=0,$ $|1-e^{it}| \approx |t|.$

(2) Consider $\ln (1-z).$

The last question: You could try $f(z) = \exp {(1+z)/(1-z)}.$ This is in the Nevanlinna class, because $\log^+|f(re^{it})|$ has a harmonic majorant (namely the Poisson kernel). So try to show $f\not \in H^p, 0<p<\infty,$

Comment: How can hint (1) help?

Comment: I'm glad you asked. I changed my hint a bit by going to the boundary. I think it's simpler now. See if this helps.