# If a function belongs to the Hardy space

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $\mathbb D= \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$. Let $\operatorname{Hol}(\mathbb {D})$  denote the space of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb D$. The Hardy spaces on $\mathbb D$ are defined as follows.

$$H^p=\{f\in \operatorname{Hol}(\mathbb {D}):\sup_{r<1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|^p d\theta<\infty\}\;\;\;(0<p<\infty)$$

$$H^\infty=\{f\in \operatorname{Hol}(\mathbb {D}):\sup_{z\in\mathbb D}|f(z)|<\infty\}$$

It is known that the function $\ln(1-z)$ belongs to $H^p$ for $0<p<\infty$ but does not belong to $H^\infty$ . Can anyone tell how?

Comment: You have got it mixed up. $\ln(1-z)$ is unbounded, hence it cannot belong to $H^{\infty}$. However the log is a typical BMOA-function and it is well know by the John-Nirenberg inequality that BMOA is contained in all $H^{p}$-spaces, $p>0$

Comment: @TheOscillator Actually my question arises from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343423/show-that-the-inclusion-relation-of-hardy-spaces-is-proper. Here it says ln(1-z) is bounded. Hence I asked.

Comment: No, you also got this wrong. He claims that $\ln(1-z)$ is an unbounded function in all $H^{p}$-spaces.

Comment: Oh no. My bad. I will correct my question. Thank you.