# About strict inclusion in Hardy spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $\mathbb D= \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$. Let $Hol(\mathbb {D})$  denote the space of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb D$. The Hardy spaces on $\mathbb D$ are defined as follows.

$$H^p=\{f\in Hol(\mathbb {D}):\sup_{r<1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta}|^pd\theta<\infty\}\;\;\;(0<p<\infty)$$

$$H^\infty=\{f\in Hol(\mathbb {D}):\sup_{z\in\mathbb D}|f(z)|<\infty\}$$
To show that $H^q$ is a strict subset of $H^p$ if $0<p<q\leq\infty$, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343423/show-that-the-inclusion-relation-of-hardy-spaces-is-proper?noredirect=1&lq=1), they say as a hint to look at functions of the form $f_a(z)=1/(1-z)^a$ for $a>0$. 
Can anyone explain how this works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that the inclusion relation of Hardy spaces is proper](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343423/show-that-the-inclusion-relation-of-hardy-spaces-is-proper)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the first question at the link you give. When you say "they" you mean me. It would be better to ask your questions there.

Comment: @zhw I totally understand what you suggest me to do. I needed a clearer explanation for hint (1). But since my reputation is less than 50, I cannot  comment on that answer. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: OK, we'll stay right here in that case. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: One idea is to consider the functions $(1-z)^{-a},a>0.$ So we're trying to understand

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{dt}{|1-re^{it}|^a}$$

as $r\to 1^-.$ To get an idea of what's happening, suppose we brashly let $r=1.$ We're then looking at

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{dt}{|1-e^{it}|^a}.$$

Now $|1-e^{it}|$ lies between constant mulitples of $|t|,$ so the values of $a$ for which the last integral converges are evident.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also explain how value of $|1-e^{it}|$ lies between constant multiples of $|t|?$

Comment: $|1-e^{it}|/|t|$ is never $0$ on $[-\pi,\pi]\setminus \{0\}$ and has limit $1$ at $0.$

Comment: Ok.  Thank you.................